# SQL select converting transaction rows to columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that lists all transactions as follows:

```
ID  Account Date    Amount
---------------------------
1   2   02/01/2015  30
2   5   05/01/2015  25
3   2   05/01/2015  12
4   2   07/01/2015  42
5   5   10/012015   19
6   2   11/01/2015  58
7   3   15/01/2015  36
```

Would like to write a select statement that will list only the last 3 transactions of each account, as follows please.

```
Account Date1   Amount      Date2   Amount      Date3   Amount
---------------------------------------------------------------
2       11/01/2015  58      07/01/2015  42      05/01/2015  12
3       15/01/2015  36              
5       10/01/2015  19      05/01/2015  25
```

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` function in a derived table to partition the data by account, and give each date within the partition a number, and then do a conditional aggregation over the rows with the top 3 numbers, grouped by account:

```
select 
    account,
    date1  = max(case when rn = 1 then date   end),
    amount = max(case when rn = 1 then amount end),
    date2  = max(case when rn = 2 then date   end),
    amount = max(case when rn = 2 then amount end),
    date3  = max(case when rn = 3 then date   end),
    amount = max(case when rn = 3 then amount end)
from (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by account order by date desc) 
    from your_table
) a
where rn <= 3
group by account
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/667e6/1)

Comment: jpw, thank you! Quick reply and solved my problem exactly. Not sure if it is was you who submitted the answer using the WITH statement, which has gone now. Had gone down this route myself and it became ever more complex. Your answer is simple = brilliance. Cheers